# how do I edit the php ini file on aws server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ini

Hey guys I have a aws EC2 Instance running however I need to edit the 
`upload_max_filesize` and the `post_max_size` in the php ini file. Im having trouble locating this file. How would I got about finding it? I need to upload bigger files than I currently can. Thanks!

Comment: At the console type `php --ini`. The will give you the path to the php.ini file. Some systems have more than one version of PHP installed (command line and web server versions). Type `which -a php` to check for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually easier to create an .htaccess file and place it in the root directory of your EC2 instance. filling the file with the values you need like this.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 3000M
php_value post_max_size 3000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
```

this keeps you from directly editing php's configuration directly and makes it much easier to maintain.

Comment: That is actually good point, my php skillz are a bit rusty. Upvoted :).

Comment: It doesn't take effect. still the old values are in charge.

Answer (score 1):

You can create .php page with:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

That should show you where currently used php.ini is located.

Usually it might be at:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

But checking with that phpinfo file is safer.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html ? That "usually" tip was for Linux machines, was just guessing as you didnt mention any OS. If you would add more details to your question, as OS of host machine, application server (Apache?), you might get more precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution **(updated on May 2023)**

php.ini file found on `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`

You can change the values here and restart the Apache Server.

It will work.

I have created a complete tutorial for this.

Please have a look at [php.ini aws ec2 tutorial](https://8subjects.com/3-easy-steps-to-change-php-configuration-in-aws-ec2-ubuntu-server-php-ini-ec2/)